# Floating elements to right side

Tags: html, css, sass

```
 <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li class="navbar__brand">
          <img src="imgs/logo.webp" alt="logo" class="navbar__brand--logo" />
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Performance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Get started</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <div class="navbar__buttons">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Sign up</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

In the above code , I want the div with the class `navbar__buttons` to be floated to the right side and aligned vertically with the other `navbar__item` items .

what I already Have : 
[image]

**here is my css**

```
  width: 100%;


  &__item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;

    transform: translateY(-1rem);

    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 2rem;
    }
  }

  &__brand {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2rem;

    width: 14rem;

    &--logo {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }


  &__buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
```

I want the div with class `navbar__buttons` to be floated right and in the same row as the rest of the navbar items

**Note : I'm using css/scss**

Comment: Exactly where are you using `float`?

Comment: I remove it from the code because it wasn't working well

Comment: I want the last two <li> elements to be on the right side

Comment: What does "not working well" mean?

Comment: It moves the elements to top right instead of moving them to right side

Comment: So you need to show us **what you are trying to achieve** and what you actually get in a [mcve]

Comment: I've added image of what i want to achieve , check it

Comment: Check the edited post please

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: .25em;
}

li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__brand">
      <img src="imgs/logo.webp" alt="logo" class="navbar__brand--logo" />
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Performance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Get started</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Sign up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the layout you're looking for using `flex` CSS properties on your elements.

First, I'd tweak your HTML slightly by moving `navbar__buttons` outside of `navbar__list`:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" alt="logo" class="navbar__brand--logo" />
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Performance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Get started</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar__buttons">
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Sign up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
      <a class="navbar__link" href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This will allow you to utilize the `flex` properties as I outline below.

Displaying your `navbar` as `flex` allows you to utilize `justify-content: space-between;`, which essentially distributes the `navbar`'s children evenly on the line, with the first element on the left and the last element on the right, thus pushing your `navbar__buttons` to the right side:

```
.navbar {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

From there, your `navbar__buttons` links would be aligned to the top (aka not aligned with your other nav links). So, you need to also add a few `flex` properties to your `navbar__buttons`:

```
.navbar__buttons {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Displaying `navbar_buttons` as `flex` allows you to use `align-items: flex-end;`, which aligns it's children to the bottom of the container, aligning them with the rest of your nav links.

Here's a working codepen example based on your code: https://codepen.io/mmshr/pen/eaOWPW